# Can't I use the old Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox, mac, firefox-extensions

I recently formatted my computer and then installed the latest Firefox : 29.0.1 and now when I tried to access Firefox Sync, it asked me to make a new account.

Last time I checked, all I had was a `Recovery Key`. I used to recover my account using the recovery key and the get all the settings that I had already done and all the bookmarks.

All my bookmarks were saved in the earlier sync and no where am I getting the option of adding the recovery key.

All my other accounts passwords were also stored with the earlier sync.

I don't know what to do. Is there a method to get all my past data back?

P.S - I still have my old recovery key.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my first answer because it was unrelated.

## Instructions

1. Uninstall Firefox 29.0.1
2. Install Firefox 28 or earlier
3. Sign in with the old Firefox
4. Install Firefox 29.0.1 ***WITHOUT*** uninstalling the old one: ( You can also do it from Help > About Firefox)

Press «Upgrade» during the installation and choose to import everything.

Now, for future reasons, make an account with the data that got imported.

This one should work.